# Spawning a process from ArcGIS ToolValidator

Tags: python, arcpy

I attempted to spawn a separate process from the ArcGIS ToolValidator script.  Unfortunately, it launches another instance of ArcCatalog.

1. What is going on behind the scenes that causes ArcCatalog to be launched, when I'm only trying to execute a second python script in a separate process and get the results?
2. How can I launch a separate process, wait for it to end, and get the results (standard out)?

Don't worry, I'm not trying to do heavy lifting from inside the tool dialog.  I was just trying to [bypass the background processing window when calling GetCount_management](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17206/getcount-management-from-arcgis-toolvalidator).  That problem was solved, but I'm still curious why ArcCatalog gets launched.

Comment: What syntax and parameters are you using to spawn the subprocess? i.e. are you using sys.executable to try and get the path to the python executable (which won't work when running from ArcCatalog)? Can you post a simple example?

Comment: I used subprocess.call with a path to an existing python script.  I just did some tests I tossed, I'll set it up again if you have suggestions to try.

Answer (score 2):

The following works for me in a ToolValidator class:

```
import sys,subprocess,os.path
subprocess.call([os.path.join(sys.exec_prefix,'pythonw'),path_to_script, script_arg_1,...,script_arg_N])
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to execute a piece of code rather than a whole script, it might be worth your while to look at the Multiprocessing module.

It will create a new process with separate resources, though still allowing you to share information between processes, if you so choose.  The typical frame for this would be:

```
import multiprocessing as _mp

def _target(var1, var2):
    import arcpy #(if required) 
    #do work here
    pass

def main():
    process = _mp.Process(target=target, kwargs=(var1='data', var2='data')
    try:

        process.start()
        print process.pid
    except Exception, ex:
        print ex
    finally:
        process.terminate()
        process.join()
```

if you would like to transfer data between the processes, check out the python [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) pages

Comment: Just to add, I have no idea why ArcCatalog would need to spawn a second instance.  I guess its just a feature!

Comment: Thanks.  I started with the multiprocessing module, and it also launches an instance of ArcCatalog.  I'll get my tests set up again and respond back...